# Date Helper Editing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror, view-helpers

I am new to Rails. I tried to use date helper in a form for the user to enter his date of birth. In migration I created "dateofbirth" column set to type -"String". Now creating a record goes good. But, when I try to edit the record I am getting error. I searched various forms, I learnt about multi-parameter assignments, but I don't understand how to retrieve them seperately and make my update work. I am attaching an image of the error I got! Appreciate any help! Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

down your migration and change field type "string" to "datetime".

I think it will help you

Comment: Actually that did solve my problem ! Thank you very much ! I actually used type as "date" as I am just working with date instead of "datatime"

Comment: Can I get your facebook link or linkedin , so that I can just ask you if any problems are there! I am working on a project ! So any help is good !Thank you!